# How/where does Qt3d assign default values to shader uniforms?

Tags: shader, qt3d

In Qt's [Qt 3D Wireframe QML example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt3d-wireframe-example.html), the [vertex shader code](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt3d-wireframe-shaders-robustwireframe-vert.html) looks as follows:

```
#version 330 core

in vec3 vertexPosition;
in vec3 vertexNormal;

out EyeSpaceVertex {
    vec3 position;
    vec3 normal;
} vs_out;

uniform mat4 modelView;
uniform mat3 modelViewNormal;
uniform mat4 mvp;

void main()
{
    vs_out.normal = normalize( modelViewNormal * vertexNormal );
    vs_out.position = vec3( modelView * vec4( vertexPosition, 1.0 ) );

    gl_Position = mvp * vec4( vertexPosition, 1.0 );
}
```

None of the `uniform` variables above are initialized in the example's source code, so they must receive default values as explained in the doc for [ShaderProgram](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qt3d-render-shaderprogram.html), which states:

> Qt3D will automatically populate a set of default uniforms if they are encountered during the shader instrospection phase.

The list of "default uniforms" is given as well.

I tried to find the part in the Qt source code where these uniforms are assigned their default values (which I guess are identity matrices), but couldn't somehow. 
Any ideas?

Comment: Have a look into functions `setShaderAndUniforms` and `initializeStandardUniformSetters` under Qt\5.13.0\Src\qt3d\src\render\renderers\opengl\renderer\renderview.cpp

Comment: @vre Thank you for taking the time! I feel a bit silly for not finding this info myself though. Cheers!

Comment: @vre Add it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The initialization of the uniforms can be found e.g. for Qt 5.13.0 in the functions [setShaderAndUniforms](https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qt3d.git/tree/src/render/renderers/opengl/renderer/renderview.cpp?h=5.13.0#n924) and [initializeStandardUniformSetters](https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qt3d.git/tree/src/render/renderers/opengl/renderer/renderview.cpp?h=5.13.0#n112) in the Qt3d module under [./Src/qt3d/src/render/renderers/opengl/renderer/renderview.cpp](https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qt3d.git/tree/src/render/renderers/opengl/renderer/renderview.cpp?h=5.13.0).